# JSF design and @Stateless @EJB @PersistenceContext explanation/usage

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I am building a web application with NetBeans 8.0.2 using JSF (2.2) and EclipseLink (JPA 2.1).

Let's assume that the current functionality is quiet basic inlcuding: login, logout, register, user roles, pages available only to admins (by using filters) etc.

I have read maaany SO Q&A (mostly from [@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc), thanks!) and would like to verify that my design is correct/follows best practices.

Currently I have:

### A user Entity (UserEntity.java)

Maybe this name is redundant, but I wanted an obvious name to begin with), corresponding to the user in database:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "UserEntity.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM UserEntity u")...})

public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "userID")
    private Integer userID;
    ...
}
```

### A user bean (User.java)

It uses the `UserService` and keeps a relevant `UserEntity`. Its methods are used in the EL of the .xhtml files

```
@ManagedBean(name = "user")  // name not needed here, but I kind of like it
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable {
    private UserEntity userEntity;      // with getter or make this public to be accessed directly from EL?

    public String login() {
        userEntity = UserService.find(username);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

### And a UserService.java

which basically has the database access methods:

```
public class UserService {
    public static String insertUser(UserEntity user) {
            String retMessage;
            EntityManager em = JPAResource.factory.createEntityManager();
            EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

            tx.begin();
            try {
                em.persist(user);
                tx.commit();
                retMessage = "ok";
                return retMessage;
            }
            catch (PersistenceException e) {
                if (tx.isActive()) tx.rollback();
                retMessage = e.getMessage();
                return retMessage;
            }
            finally {
                em.close();
            }
    }
    ...
}
```

At some point I noticed that the UserService could have only static methods, so I can access them without creating instances.

Is that bad and why?

---

I guess the correct way would be to have the UserService as:
    import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
    import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
    ...

```
@Stateless
public class UserService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public static String insertUser(UserEntity user)
    {
        em.persist(user);
    }
    ...
}
```

and the user bean as:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "user")
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    private UserEntity userEntity;

    public String login() {
        userEntity = UserService.find(username);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Is that correct?

I am not sure what exactly the `@Stateless`, `@EJB`, `PersistenceContext` do/mean.
(Are they from `javax.ejb.Stateless`, `javax.ejb.EJB`, `javax.persistence.PersistenceContext` respectively?)

Does using `@Stateless` and `@EJB` allow me to utilize my `UserService` without creating instances of it and without having static methods?

What about checking the transactions? Does `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` have me covered? i.e. no need for further checks? If an exception is thrown, will the method `return` with the relevant message?

With `@PersistenceContext`, what/who is creating the `EntityManager` instance?

Is this design good practice, respecting the separation of concerns etc?

Thanks!

---

### See also:

- [stackoverflow.com/questions/16526267/javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-in-small-facelet-application/16542568#16542568](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526267/javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-in-small-facelet-application/16542568#16542568)
- [JSF managed-bean EJB injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626291/jsf-managed-bean-ejb-injection)

Comment: You are using JSF 2.2. Who always recommends a session scoped bean in situations where a narrower scoped bean is sufficient?

Comment: Not sure why you mention that. If the `User` class has the login method, the currently-logged-in userinfo etc, then it should be session scoped. No?

Comment: Never. A managed bean used to login can never be a session scoped bean - it is just not required. Any session scoped information is to be placed in a separate session scoped bean.

Comment: So you are saying that it is wrong to also keep the login method in the bean I use for the user's session? Why is that?

Comment: I did not mention anything about methods in that bean. Having any method is legit. Just that it unnecessarily carries a verbose session scoped bean in a place where a narrower scoped bean suffices adequately.

Comment: JSF 1.x examples somewhere may be using session scoped beans for this kind of things at the time, when view scope did not exist.

Comment: What I am saying is that it needs the session scope, because it carries the user session.

Comment: A login form is no longer different than any other normal form with basically two input fields and a submit button. You basically need to maintain its state during post backs exactly as that needed during performing basic CRUD operations which a view scoped bean is sufficient for (If you need not maintain any state during post backs, then the bean is to be placed simply in a request scope). You can always create a separate session scoped bean (one or more) to store session scoped information as stated earlier and inject that bean wherever necessary.

Comment: So, having separate beans for information I could otherwise have merged, is a good practice. Ok, will look into that, thanks!

Comment: It depends upon business requirements, readability, maintainability etc (for example, one can design separate forms with separate managed beans for Read, Insert and Edit/Update or use a single managed bean with a single form/page - it depends upon the nature of the application).

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao and the links therein (and the links therein (and the links therein (etc))) answers everything you need to know.

Comment: I have read some of those, but I can see some "unread" ones. Will check them all out. Thanks @BalusC (for everything around here :) )

Answer (score 1):

`@Stateless` is the way to go instead of static methods. If you use NetBeans you can auto-generate these `@Stateless` classes, they are called facades there (in NetBeans -> right mouse click on pacakge -> new -> session beans for entity classes and choose entities).

You don't create `EJB` instances on your own, you just use `@EJB` annotations and container will provide you "instance".

For transactions you have separate annotations you can read about `javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute`. You just annotate `EJB` classes/methods with them and given `javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType` and that's everything, container will start/end/nest(hold back) transactions for you.

For the part about `@SessionScoped` it can be your controller. Let's say you have 5 xhtml pages. Then you create 5 backing beans (`@RequestScoped`/`@ViewScoped` etc.) and use `@Inject` in every of them with the controller class. So your backing beans narrow their logic to only 1 page and then forwards further actions to controller class. Controller class can have methods (API) with only 1 line which forwards actions to `EJB`. In EJB you can have service (`@Stateful`) which communicates with this controller, this service communicates with other classes (like backing beans previously but now just call them managers) and managers have business logic. This logic can persist data to database through previously generated facades (`@Stateless`).

You don't need filters with `EJB` to control roles, you can use annotation `javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed` and specify which method can be invoked by which role.

That's my point of view, it may not be complex explanation but there is plenty of staff which you can google using the keywords.

EDIT:

Don't use JSF annotations like `@ManagedBean` and `@ManagedProperty`. Better use newer technology like CDI `@Named` and `@Inject`.

Comment: So, `@Stateless` along with `@EJB` have me covered and I won't need to manually create an instance of my UserService. Regarding the transactions, I've editted the original question to include these. About the roles, it is quite a different subject; will look into it and maybe create a new question. 
Will wait for a few more inputs. Thanks for sharing your opinion on the matter!

Comment: Inject EJBs/managed beans without using `new`in which you can only have a new unmanaged instance.