# How to inject EntityManager in CDI (weld)?

Tags: jpa, cdi, wildfly, entitymanager, weld

In my project , I use JSF+JPA+CDI+WildFly 8.2 in the persistence layer. I have a BasicDao , like this:

```
 public  class BasicDao<M, K> {
    private org.jboss.logging.Logger logger = org.jboss.logging.Logger
           .getLogger("BasicDao");

    @Inject
    @Primary
    protected EntityManager em;
    Class<M> mclass;

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional(value=TxType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public M find(K id){ 
        return em.find(mclass, id);
    }

    @Transactional(value=TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void insert(M inst){
        this.em.persist(inst);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(value=TxType.REQUIRED)
    public K insertWithAutoId(M inst){
        this.em.persist(inst);
        return (K) this.em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(inst);
    }

    @Transactional(value=TxType.REQUIRED)
    public M update(M updated){
        return this.em.merge(updated);
    }


    @Transactional(value=TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void delete(M nonUsed){
        this.em.remove(nonUsed);
    }
}
```

and the other DAOs like this :

```
@RequestScoped
public class UserDao extends BasicDao<User, Integer>{

    @Transactional(value = TxType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public User find(Integer id) {
        return em.find(User.class, id);
    }

    @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void insert(User inst) {
        this.em.persist(inst);
    }

    @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
    public Integer insertWithAutoId(User inst) {
        this.em.persist(inst);
        return (Integer) this.em.getEntityManagerFactory()
                .getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(inst);
    }

    @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
    public User update(User updated) {
        return this.em.merge(updated);
    }

    @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void delete(User nonUsed) {
        this.em.remove(nonUsed);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(value = TxType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public User findByName(String loginName) {

        Query query = em.createQuery("select u from User u where u.loginName=:loginName");
        List<User> users = (List<User>) query.setParameter("loginName",
                loginName).getResultList();
        return users.isEmpty() ? null : users.get(0);
    }
}
```

In my ManageredBean,the code likes this:

```
 @Inject
 private UserDao userDao;
```

but it often throws exception, not always. I was very confused. The exception stack like this:

```
09:50:59,945 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-27) JSF1073：在 RENDER_RESPONSE 6 的处理过程中捕捉到 com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException：UIComponent-ClientId=，Message=对受管 bean resumeAudit 执行资源注入 (resource injection) 时发生错误  
09:50:59,946 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-27) 对受管 bean resumeAudit 执行资源注入 (resource injection) 时发生错误: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: 对受管 bean resumeAudit 执行资源注入 (resource injection) 时发生错误  
  at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:227) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]  
  at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]  
  at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]  
  at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]  
  at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.LabelRenderer.encodeBegin(LabelRenderer.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at com.wangyin.hzcrp.auth.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:109) [classes:]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)  
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)  
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance  
  at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JSFInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(JSFInjectionProvider.java:63) [wildfly-jsf-injection-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]  
  at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]  
  ... 70 more  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:162)  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:133)  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:100)  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentRegistry$ComponentManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ComponentRegistry.java:171)  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentRegistry.createInstance(ComponentRegistry.java:87)  
  at org.jboss.as.web.common.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:77)  
  at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JSFInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(JSFInjectionProvider.java:61) [wildfly-jsf-injection-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]  
  ... 71 more  
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void com.wangyin.hzcrp.controller.ResumeAudit.init() on com.wangyin.hzcrp.controller.ResumeAudit@628e5ac9  
  at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:100) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BeanInjectionTarget.java:70) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldComponentIntegrationProcessor$3.run(WeldComponentIntegrationProcessor.java:196) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldComponentIntegrationProcessor$AbstractInjectionTargetDelegatingInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldComponentIntegrationProcessor.java:260) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)  
  at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:53) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)  
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)  
  at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)  
  at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)  
  at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)  
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)  
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)  
  at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)  
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)  
  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:160)  
  ... 77 more  
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  ... 100 more  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.persistence.EntityManager field com.wangyin.hzcrp.storage.dao.BasicDao.em to com.wangyin.hzcrp.storage.dao.ResumeDao$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass  
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]  
  at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:94) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:370) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:381) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]  
  at com.wangyin.hzcrp.storage.dao.ResumeDao$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.find(Unknown Source) [crp-storage-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]  
  at com.wangyin.hzcrp.controller.ResumeAudit.init(ResumeAudit.java:81) [classes:]  
  ... 105 more
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks a million.

Comment: You will have to use a CDI producer to make an `EntityManager` instance available in your CDI managed beans. See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#declaring_disposer_method) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv-examples003.htm#JEETT01139). Do not call `EntityManager#close()` on a container-managed `EntityManager` (using `@Disposes`). Otherwise, the container will throw a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` by specification.

Comment: @Tiny Thanks for answering. Here is my prodecer,  `public class UtilResource {
 @Produces
 @Primary
 @PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
 private EntityManager em;
}`   i did as you said, but is also throwed exception. I hope you can help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8763115/1391249) for a concrete example usage. The Oracle example in the earlier comment of mine is not a plausible thing to do - using a producer in a `@Singleton` bean may expose the `EntityManager` to many threads. Also, the container is not required to support any other scope than `@Dependent` (default) while using a **producer field**. Go for a **producer method** instead using `@RequestScoped` as mentioned in that example.

Comment: @Tiny like this?  `@ApplicationScoped
public class UtilResource {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

 @Produces
 public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
  return entityManager;
 }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        if (em != null && em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        if (em != null && em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I did not test that example myself, since I am mostly concerned with a container-managed `EntityManager` in EJBs but it should work.

Answer (score 19):

The appropriate way to inject a Persistent Context into a managed Bean is the following:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "my-pu-name")
private EntityManager em;
```

Note that this can only be done on managed beans, ie, beans that are created/destroyed by the container.

A best practice is to add this as as a producer, so that you can just use `@Inject` into your managed beans:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationResources {
    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my-pu-name")
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

Then, you can inject it in JAX-RS endpoints, EJBs and any other bean that is managed by the container:

```
@Stateless
public class FooService {
    @Inject
    EntityManager em;
}
```

Comment: where should I put persistence.xml ?

Comment: With this class a need to close the EntityManager?