# Cant inject EntityManager With @PersistenceContext in most basic example

Tags: java, maven, jpa, jboss, persistence-manager

To test JPA with PersistenceContext injection of entity manager I have basic example project with following structure:
Person entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        if (id != person.id) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(person.name) : person.name != null) return false;
        return surname != null ? surname.equals(person.surname) : person.surname == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (surname != null ? surname.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Rest config :

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestConfig extends Application {
}
```

Test rest endpoint:

```
@Path("/test")
//@Vetoed
public class TestResource {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @GET
    @Path("/dbtest")
    public Response testDb() {
        System.out.println("DBG Invocation of dbtest");
        Person person=new Person("tomas","bisciak");
        entityManager.persist(person); //ALWAYS NULL
        System.out.println("Persisted");
        Person retrievedEntity= entityManager.find(Person.class,1);
        System.out.println("Retrieved entity:"+retrievedEntity);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS2</jta-data-source>

        <class>Person</class>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xchange" />

            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Datasource defined in my wildfly standalone.xml:

```
 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS2" pool-name="MySqlDS2" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xchange</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

Project structure with war structure:

[image]

And following inside of my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bisciak.jpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpatest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Testing dependencies-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

All of this is running on latest stable Wildfly, output that i get is :

```
Connected to server
[2018-01-29 03:17:37,085] Artifact jpatest:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
15:17:37,168 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT" (runtime-name: "jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
15:17:38,312 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
15:17:38,351 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final
15:17:38,516 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 6.0)
15:17:38,537 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) WELD-000900: 2.4.3 (Final)
15:17:38,574 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_6_0
15:17:38,896 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1978)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0037: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named 'pu' in deployment jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war for injection point private javax.persistence.EntityManager TestResource.entityManager
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldJpaInjectionServices.getScopedPUName(WeldJpaInjectionServices.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.bootstrap.WeldJpaInjectionServices.registerPersistenceContextInjectionPoint(WeldJpaInjectionServices.java:77)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$PersistenceContextResourceInjectionProcessor.getResourceReferenceFactory(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:350)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$PersistenceContextResourceInjectionProcessor.getResourceReferenceFactory(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:338)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$ResourceInjectionProcessor.createFieldResourceInjection(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:216)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory$ResourceInjectionProcessor.createResourceInjections(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:188)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory.discoverType(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:448)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ResourceInjectionFactory.getResourceInjections(ResourceInjectionFactory.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.<init>(ResourceInjector.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.of(ResourceInjector.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.<init>(BeanInjectionTarget.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.createDefault(BeanInjectionTarget.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.chooseInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.<init>(ManagedBean.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.of(ManagedBean.java:80)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createManagedBean(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:261)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:71)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

15:17:38,896 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0037: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named 'pu' in deployment jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war for injection point private javax.persistence.EntityManager TestResource.entityManager"}}
15:17:38,911 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0037: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named 'pu' in deployment jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war for injection point private javax.persistence.EntityManager TestResource.entityManager"}}
15:17:38,911 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver_6_0
15:17:38,963 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT (runtime-name: jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war) in 62ms
[2018-01-29 03:17:39,010] Artifact jpatest:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2018-01-29 03:17:39,010] Artifact jpatest:war exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0037: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named 'pu' in deployment jpatest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war for injection point private javax.persistence.EntityManager TestResource.entityManager"}}
```

**Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named 'pu'**

Or **null pointer on entityManager** when i use @Vetoed on TestResource class.

**What exactly im doing wrong that i cant inject container managed entityManager with @PersistenceContext?**

Im trying to understand this since for everyone else this seems to be working.

**Please dont tell me to use application managed transactions, I can make that work bud I NEED CONTAINER MANAGED entityMnanager , so i need to inject it with**

@PersistenceContext(unitName="")

**Notes & Edits:**

What i use:
Intellij,Wildfly,eclipselink,Java EE7,Maven,MySQL

In addition my beans.xml has nothing in it just beans discovery mode set to all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

I have tried multiple annotation on my Resource class, always failed to inject em:
[image]

Comment: Add your java classes into a package. Update your persistence.xml file with the full qualified name <class><your.package>.Person</class>

Comment: @Luca Montagnoli this is just quick example, i have 2 other projects that have multi layer package structure, same problem there. This suggestion does not solve my problem.

Comment: Seems "persistence.xml" file doesn't properly load. Try with a minimal version commenting all the properties.

Comment: @Luca Montagnoli tried now, still same problem.

Comment: Can you please share your code, I'll download it and test on my side. It should work.

Comment: @Rouliboy i will create git repo ;)

Comment: @Rouliboy upped it , with target as well so you can see war structure:  https://github.com/TomasBisciak/SO48503545.git

Comment: wildfly uses hibernate as jpa provider, and you are using eclipselink in your pom.. I would try removing eclipselink dependency.. So there are no previous errors while deploying?

Comment: @mendieta I just checked something about this, so even if i try to use eclipselink, it uses hibernate? Btw i had this problem initially with hibernate, i tough that problem might be related to hibernate, so i switched to eclipselink, bud problem is still there, ;D so i guess that wont be a cause, bud i can try again maybe i missed something.

Comment: wildfly will try to use the provider set in the persistence.xml, but it could be that it isn't finding the EclipseLink class in its class path or with what ever loader it is trying to use. You might try Hibernate just to see if it gets further, and enable hibernate logging, as hibernate will be built into the container and so be loaded differently.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are not using a EJB, which supports `EntityManager` injection, you have to use the `EntityManagerFactory` to create and destroy an EntityManager.

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
```

After using it always close the "entityManager"

```
entityManager.close();
```

Otherwise turn your resource into an EJB, adding `@Stateless`.

Comment: I specifically mentioned this in my question, i know i can make this work with what you just wrote, bud this is not the solution - this wont get you container managed entity manager. I can use EJB annoatations  bud i sitll have same problem.

Comment: neither of the Stateless or Statefull work. em still null.

Comment: You missed a dependency: 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: It's just wrong. Java EE 7 allow inject all EJB-aware beans into CDI beans, including Stateless, Statefull, EntityManager/EntityFactory and resources of Application server. Even in WIldfly of version 8 it work correctly.